# Move wp-content outside root

Tags: wp-config

I have moved my wp-content folder up one folder level from where my wp installation is:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-content' );
```

By doing this, the wp-content folder is now above the root folder which the server has configured. This seems to break all links to the js and css files in the theme...

The purpose of this is to make it easier to control the theme with git and control the wp version with composer. I do not intent to move the wp-content folder outside of the root folder for the web server (I guess that this is what is causing the problems with the js and css files) but I do not want the wp installation in a sub folder so that the url to my site is at www.mysite.com/wp either.

So, how do I solve it so that my wp installation is avaliable at www.mysite.com while wp-content is moved outside of the wp installation folder?

Comment: Alias in your Apache config?

Comment: Possible duplicate: (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41626/moving-wp-content-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: You may want to look at Mark Jaquith's WPSkeleton setup: https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton This allows WordPress to be in the subdirectory. I don't believe you can put the wp-content outside the root HTML folder unless you create a symlink to it.